# docker-compose up ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am beginner on docker and i am trying to run a flask python app and I have the following problem when running `docker-compose up`, throws error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'**

This is a picture of the error:
[docker-compose up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn3ui.png)

This is the files in my current directory
[my local directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Tz7.png)

this is the content of my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

this is the content of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  helloworld:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

this is my requirements.txt

```
click==8.1.2
Flask==2.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.2
importlib-metadata==4.11.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
mysqlclient==2.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.35
Werkzeug==2.1.1
zipp==3.8.0
```

this is my app.py

```
from distutils.log import debug
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from models import Base
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Flask sss"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I tried tearing it down with `docker-compose down` and when running `docker-compose up` again same error.
Can someone point me to the right direction of how i can run flask app successfully ?

Comment: `docker-compose up --build` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

And for your docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  helloworld:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
```

To build up your container, you can directly run this inliner:

`docker-compose down; docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans`

If the above doesn't help, I'd inspection the container directly from inside. You can access it with the following:

```
docker-compose exec helloworld sh
```

From there, navigates to the directory with the files and make sure everything is where it's supposed to be; If files are messed up or missing, make sure your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` (on your local pc) are in the root directory of your project.

That should help, but reach out in the comments if not!

Comment: It worked out the dockerfile, the docker-compose.yml and command

docker-compose down; docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans

Can you explain to me why it worked out, was it because i needed to add the --no-cache-dir flag ?

Comment: That's one option, or it could be you just had to rebuild your container - Images documentation on docker hub are great places for setting up new containers as they provide basic examples to reuse: https://hub.docker.com/_/python